# Where does this compiling error come from?

Tags: java

I am getting quite frustrated right now, and the main source of my frustration is the following error:

```
LogicalAutomaton.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
        Cellular[i][j] = new Cellular (null, Cellular[i+1][j], null, Cellular[i][j+1]);
        ^
symbol:   variable Cellular
location: class LogicalAutomaton
```

The class hierarchy is the following:

```
home --> code --> Automata --> automata
```

And here is the code:

This is the class Cellular.java, in home/code/Automata/automata:

```
package automata;

public class Cellular {

  private int state;
  private Cellular upper, lower, left, right;

  public Cellular (Cellular upper, Cellular lower, Cellular left,Cellular right) {
    this.state = 0;
    this.upper = upper;
    this.lower = lower;
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
  }

}
```

And this is the class LogicalAutomaton.java, in home/code/Automata:

```
import automata.Cellular;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class LogicalAutomaton extends Cellular {

  public static void main (String[] args) {

    int n = 3;
    Cellular[][] a = new Cellular[n][n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (i == 0) {
          if (j == 0) {
            Cellular[i][j] = new Cellular (null, Cellular[i+1][j], null, Cellular[i][j+1]);
          }
          else {
            if (j == n-1) {
              Cellular[i][j] = new Cellular (null, Cellular[i+1][j], Cellular[i][j-1], null);
            }
            else {
            Cellular[i][j] = new Cellular (null, Cellular[i+1][j], Cellular[i][j-1], Cellular[i][j+1]);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

  }

}
```

The code of LogicalAutomaton.java is much longer, but the main idea is to get access to the array of Cellular objects in order to initialize them, and each time I try to do this, it throws me said error. Funnily enough, the compiler does not lament the declaration of the Cellular array.

Do you have any idea where I might have done wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Edit:

Sorry for the clumsy question; here is part of the faulty code.

Comment: What is `Cellular[i][j]`?

Comment: should not that be a[i][j]...

Comment: where is code `Cellular[i][j] = new Cellular (null, Cellular[i+1][j], null, Cellular[i][j+1]);`?

Comment: Two for-loops are used, with int i and int j respectively, to go through the array elements.

Comment: @Matthias Yes, bloody hell, thank you, I should be ashamed of myself.

Comment: please post the code containing the error line `Cellular[i][j] = new Cellular (null, Cellular[i+1][j], null, Cellular[i][j+1]);`

Comment: @eslukas it is often helpful to show the code which is not working/compiling rather than the code which is working.

Comment: package home.code.Automata.automata   is this correct package path?

Comment: No, the package is simply automata, I run LogicalAutomaton from Automata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define your array as

```
Cellular[][] a = new Cellular[n][n];
```

but then later on, you use

```
Cellular[i][j] = new Cellular (null, Cellular[i+1][j], null, Cellular[i][j+1]);
```

when in fact, you should be using

```
a[i][j] = new Cellular (null, Cellular[i+1][j], null, Cellular[i][j+1]);
```

The error message you are getting

> LogicalAutomaton.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
>           Cellular[i][j] = new Cellular (null, Cellular[i+1][j], null, Cellular[i][j+1]);
>           ^ symbol:   variable Cellular location: class LogicalAutomaton

is saying I cannot find a variable named Cellular, not that I cannot find the class. This is because you have not defined a variable called *Cellular*, the variable you have defined is called *a*.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is because of accessibility. The `Cellular` class is not accessible in the `LogicalAutomoton` class. Check your CLASSPATH variable and check whether the import statement is correct.